# Не могу решить задание с codeforces "красивый год"

Tags: python

[image]

помогите решить задание с CodeForces. Не могу придумать способ проверки различности цифр в числе. Пробовал через множества, однако ничего не получилось

```
year=[i+1 for i in range(999, 10000)]
lucky_year=set()
for i in range(1000, len(year)):
    god=list(map(int, str(int(i))))
    print(god)
    for j in god:
        lucky_year.add(j)
print(lucky_year)
```

Comment: переводите в строку и сравнивайте буковке/циферке

Comment: Зачем сравнивать? просто подбирайте следующую цифру - ещё не использованную, минимальную из возможных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lucky_year = set()
a = []
y = int(input())
for i in range(1000, 9013):
    god = list(map(int, str(int(i))))
    for j in god:
        lucky_year.add(j)
    if len(lucky_year) == 4:
        a.append(i)
    lucky_year.clear()
for i in a:
    if y<i:
       print(i)
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал через рекурсию: просто проверяете разность кол-ва всех цифр и кол-ва уникальных цифр в следующем году.

```py
def lucky_year(year):
    year_plus = year + 1
    if len(str(year_plus)) == len(set(str(year_plus))):
        return year_plus
    return lucky_year(year_plus)

lucky_year(1987)
# 2013
```

Comment: Но рекурсия тут лишняя, вполне можно было сделать через while(True) %)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так.

```
y = input()

def checkfun(string):
    for i in range(len(string) - 1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(string)):
            if y[i] == y[j]:
                return False
    return True



while True:
    y = int(y)
    y += 1
    y = str(y)
    if not checkfun(y):
        continue
    else:
        print(y)
        break
```